# FCM Instance Id is not generated in Samsung Galaxy S8 android version 8.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an FCM implementation in a project and the FCM Instance Id seems to be not generating only in this one device(Samsung Galaxy s8, android version 8.0.0). Other than this device, it works fine on other devices. However, unfortunately I do not have access to any other oreo device right now so I cannot verify if this is an oreo issue or phone issue.

My Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ideabinbd.fcmimplementation">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".FCMInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FcmMessageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Instance Id Class:

```
public class FCMInstance extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private final String TAG="fcmToken";
public  String currentToken;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    currentToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, currentToken);
}
}
```

OnMessageReceive Service:

```
public class FcmMessageReceiver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("fcm","messageRecieved");
    String title= remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body= remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    int notifyID = 9001;
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    // Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification

    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
}
```

On my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "fcmToken";
Button invokeServer;
String url="http://10.0.3.2/fcm/fcmInsert.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
}
```

I get a null pointer exception when I try to print the token using log. Below is the logcat for the error:

> Process: com.ideabinbd.fcmimplementation, PID: 809
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ideabinbd.fcmimplementation/com.ideabinbd.fcmimplementation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>           at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>           at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:161)
>           at com.ideabinbd.fcmimplementation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)

Again, the code works fine for older versions of Android, is there any step I am missing for android 8 required to generate service id? And It is **not about Notification Channel** since receiving individual notifications will work only if I generate a token.

Comment: The docs say it returns null if it hasn't been generated yet.  Maybe test without the main activity log call and wait to see if the service logs it sometime after startup.  Only other thing I could think of is Google Play services not being installed might cause that.

Comment: Tried testing without log in Mainactivity, still doesn't work. I'll insert a code segment to check Google Play Service installed or not. But it is installed and updated most probably.

Comment: @MohaimanulChowdhury Have you get the solution.

Comment: @mukesh seems like it was a problem with the specific device, it wasn't working only in a single S8, tested in another S8+ and worked fine. Not sure what happened there